# Using a base class as parameter

Tags: c#, inheritance, parameters

I'm sure this is just a matter of me not understanding something completely obvious, but I seem to be hopefully stuck on this.

I have an abstract base class that is inherited by a large amount of other classes, to maintain security information across my application. I'll simplify for this question though.

```
public abstract class ModelBase
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class SpecificModel : ModelBase
{
    public int specificInt { get; set; }
    public string specificString { get; set; }
}
```

In this case, about 30 different classes all inherit from ModelBase.

I would like to create a method that can accept any object who's class inherits from ModelBase. So I created something like this:

```
public bool TestIt (ref ModelBase BaseModel)
{
    BaseModel.UserID = 10;
    BaseModel.UserName = "Evan";

    return true;
}
```

However, if I try to pass in an object of type SpecificModel, I get an error.

```
SpecificModel hiThere = new SpecificModel();

hiThere.specificInt = 5;
hiThere.specificString = "Oh well";

bool retVal = TestMethods.TestIt(ref hiThere);
```

The error I see on the last line is: **The best overloaded method match for 'TestMethods.TestIt(ref ModelBase)' has some invalid arguments**

What am I not "getting" here?

Thanks

Comment: Please specify the error.

Comment: where are you creating / instantiating a new instance of `SpecificModel` check out this link for example it's answer is easy to understand http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17911285/is-it-possible-to-pass-the-abstract-classs-object-as-argument-to-an-instance-of

Comment: @ByteBlast I added in the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

whats the error it throwing? 
I have tried it myself its nothing look wrong in your code. might be your calling mechanism is not correct. here is the sample code.

```
    class Program
    {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ModelBase sp = new SpecificModel2();
        TestIt(ref sp);

    }
    public static bool TestIt(ref ModelBase BaseModel)
    {
        BaseModel.UserID = 10;
        BaseModel.UserName = "Evan";

        return true;
    }
}
public abstract class ModelBase
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public class SpecificModel : ModelBase
{
    public int specificInt { get; set; }
    public string specificString { get; set; }
}

public class SpecificModel2 : ModelBase
{
    public int specificInt { get; set; }
    public string specificString { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Your code definitely works. The main difference is that I had TestIt in a different class in mine, but seeing that compile without errors gives me a solid point to work from. Thank you very much.

Comment: After looking further, I don't understand why you used: ModelBase sp = new SpecificModel2(); Won't the resulting item be the base class, not the derived class?

Comment: yes your right it was just an example for demonstration.

Answer (score 3):

You have it right, except you don't want to be passing by `ref` (likely the source of your error). Your class is already a reference type, you **probably** don't need to pass a reference to it. Given the function definition in the question;

```
public bool TestIt (ModelBase BaseModel)
{
    BaseModel.UserID = 10;
    BaseModel.UserName = "Evan";

    return true;
}
```

Will be perfect (except for the weird "always return true" but perhaps thats because this is demo code).

Comment: If I do the above, will the object I pass in reflect the changes made in TestIt ?

Comment: @ESDictor Yes; you are modifying the object pointed to by the passed parameter (reference). Passing by `ref` allows you changes to the *parameter itself* (like assignment) to reflect back to the caller.

Comment: if I make the TestIt accept a ModelBase (as in your example above),  it won't allow me to pass in an object of type SpecificModel to that method. It doesn't matter if there's a "ref" or not.

Comment: Then `SpecificModel` doesn't derive from `ModelBase`. You can *always* upcast. What error are you getting? Can you post a .NET fiddle showing the problem?

Comment: The error I am getting is "The best overloaded method match for 'TestMethods.TestIt(ref ModelBase)' has some invalid arguments". However, I see below that the answer from Sufyan Jamil appears to work fine without breaking TestIt into its own class. While I haven't gotten my application working yet, at least I feel I understand that my problem has to do with accessing that additional class.